# Following .0 in em required or preference?

Tags: css, font-size

I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

To keep it short, should I use `font-size: 2.0em;` or `font-size: 2em;`?

Comment: ... It is upto you... If you need a point value then use a . others wise  it is not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never going to be wrong to use `2.0em`.

But the near-universal convention is to use `2em`.

In 15 years of writing CSS, I'm certain I have never seen `2.0em`.

---

**That said**... *whichever* format you use, the correct attribute is:

- `font-size`

Comment: Thanks a ton! For whatever reason, both of the resources I've been learning form had made it a practice to use `2.0em`, and I'm not too sure why.

Comment: Oops, just noticed my typos! Thanks for pointing them out. I meant to type `font-size` but had `text-transform` on the mind while typing this up.

Answer (score -3):

You may not be able to find a valid answer, because this is just personal preference.

It's certainly not required. I personally only append the .XX if it's needed. It's more readable that way (to me).

Comment: `because this is just personal preference` -->this mean we should close as opinon based unless you find an accurate answer

Comment: Fair enough, but to be honest, he asked if it was required or personal preference. I answered.